# If $(X, \tau)$ is $T_1$ and there is an open-closed set basis for the $X$ topology, show that $X$ is completely regular.

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

If $(X, \tau)$ is $T_1$ and there is an open-closed set basis for the $X$ topology, show that $X$ is completely regular.

we will first remember some definitions
completely regular: A topological space $X$ is called completely regular, if
given a closed $A$ in $X$ and a point $b \in X \setminus A$, there exists a continuous function $f: X → [0, 1]$ such that $f (A) \subseteq \{0\}$ and $f (b) = 1$. All normal space is completely regular.

Let $X$ be a topological space. $X$ is said to be a $T_1$ space if
Given $x$ and $y$ in $X$ with $x \neq y$, there exist $U \in U_x$ and $V \in U_y$ such that $y \notin U$ and $x \notin V$.

I think it would be easier to test if it is possible that it is normal, but I don't know how to use the hypothesis of the closed and open base, any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in X$ be any point and $F\not\ni x$ be any closed subset of $X$. Since $X$ has a basis consisting of clospen (tht is, closed and open) sets, there exists a clopen set $U$ such that $x\in U\subset X\setminus F$. Then a function $f:X\to [0,1]$ such that $f(U)\subset \{0\}$ and $f(X\setminus U)\subset \{1\}$ is continuous and separates $x$ and $F$.

Comment: you define the continuous function like this: $f:X \rightarrow [0,1]$  as $0$ si $x \in U$, $1$ si $X \in X \setminus U$. If $f$ is continuous for each open $V$ in $[0,1]$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$, then the basic open of $[0,1]$ are, $[0,t)$ $(t,s)$, $(s, 1]$, thus $f^{-1}([0,t))=U$, $f^{-1}((t,1])=X \setminus U$ clearly $U$ and $X \setminus U$ are open in $X$, $f^{-1}(t,s)= \emptyset$ is open in $X$. Is my reasoning okay or do I have an error? where is the hypothesis that $ X $ is $T_1$?

Comment: @karolflorez You reasoning is too long. The function $f$ is continuous because a preimage $f^{-1}(V)$ of *any* subset $V$ of $[0,1]$ is open, since $f^{-1}(V)$ is one of the following sets: $\varnothing$, $U$, $X\setminus U$, $X$. The assumption that $X$ is $T_1$ is not needed for the proof, but some authors do include it in the definition of completely regular spaces.